# calling a method from constructor in python

Tags: python

I am trying call a child class method using parent class constructor.

```
class Configurator():
    config_file = "" #variable which stores config file
    input_response = "" #variable which stores input response json

    def __init__(self,config_file, input_response):
        self.config_file = config_file
        self.input_response = input_response

        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.cfg')
        if config.get('Configurator', 'ctool')  ==  'Chef':
            Configurator.__initialize(self)

    def __initialize(self):
        open_input_response = open(self.input_response, 'r')
        read_cloudprovider = json.load(open_input_response)
        cloudprovider = read_cloudprovider['CloudProvider']
        if cloudprovider == 'AWS':
            print('Working Here')
            obj = AWS()
            obj.print_test(self)


class AWS(Configurator):
    def print_test(self):
        print('I am AWS Class')


def main():
    configurator = Configurator('config.cfg', 'input_response.json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Why im getting an error, AWS has no orguments to take

Comment: Side note: I strongly encourage you to check PEP 8 (and PEP 257): this will make your code more legible for you and others. This will in particular make it easier to answer your questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: The answers below are quite good. But it is quite odd that you are having your base class instantiate an instance of something that is a child class of itself. It implies that there is something odd going on in your code.

Comment: @EOL thanks I will make sure that I will follow PEP 8

Comment: "Use the white-spaces, Luke!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods that are not overridden in the child are the same method as in the parent. `AWS.__init__()` takes two additional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following segment:

```
 obj=AWS()
 obj.print_test(self)
```

You are constructing a new instance of the class `AWS`. What should python do when creating that instance? It must call `AWS.__init__` but that method is nonexistent so it uses its parent - `Configuration.__init__`. The latter takes 3 arguments and this is why you see that error.

To fix that, you need to explicitly call `Configuration.__init__` with the correct arguments:

```
class AWS:
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        Configuration.__init__(self, "value_for_config", "value_for_input")
        ...
```

Also, please note that in your current code `Configuration.__init__` calls `AWS.__init__` which calls `Configuration.__init__` once again, this indirect recursion can easily lead to stack overflow so be careful.

Comment: Error occurred while calling `Configurator._init__` from `AWS.__init__` Error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`